# Hide status bar not work

Tags: android

I use `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` to hide `status bar`, code like this(sdk > 16):

```
 Decorview decorview = getWindow().getDecorview();
 decorview.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However, it works on some Android phones but fails on others like below:
[image: wrong status bar hidden]

What is wrong with the white satus bar? Why is it not hidden?
ps: The style is ok, just a normal one, no `fitwindowsystem`, no immersive.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @AI WId Nope. I gave up using this method and used the way like: getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); It works.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll do the same I suppose

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Android [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html), you can hide the `statusBar` like this in SDK < 16 i.e Android version lower than Jellybean :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
```

call this in your `onCreate` method, before you call `setContentView`.

and for SDK above 16 use the following code :

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying! But the sdk is above 16 and there is not action bar. I just do as in your answer but it fails on some phone.

Answer (score 0):

**1.If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

**2.Code to hide the Status Bar on 16 and Higher your Code works.**

```
 Decorview decorview = getWindow().getDecorview();
 decorview.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Note : Remember that you should never show the action bar if the status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

**3.if the status bar should always remain hidden in your app setting an activity theme in your app's manifest file.**

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying! But the sdk is above 16 and there is not action bar. I just do as in your answer but it fails on some phone